# Primary keys for a table of completely unique rows?

Tags: mysql, database

Straight into this one. I have a table for a sort of "like" feature. This table naturally has the following:

```
Name      | Type   | Attributes  | (Comment)
Post ID   | int    | index       | ID of the post which was "Liked"
Topic ID  | int    | index       | ID of the topic which contains the "Liked" post
Member ID | int    | index       | ID of the member who "Liked" the post
Date      | bigint | index       | Date/time of "Like"
```

As you can see, there's no primary key. This seems natural. The only functions which need performing are the INSERT (for "Like"), DELETE (for "Unlike") and searching for likes in order of most recent by the post or member who gave them.

Each entry will obviously be very 'UNIQUE' - as only one like is needed per person per post. There seems absolutely no need for a unique primary index, as if duplicates occur (somehow) I will want to DELETE them all, not just one with a particular ID. Same with insertion, no one can like the same thing twice. And these "likes" will only ever be selected using the indexes from other tables.

Yet, phpMyAdmin now forbids me from any manual editing, copying or deleting. This is also fine, but prompted me to further look up the logistics of not having a primary key. When I found a stackoverflow answer, the general opinion was that it's "very rare" to not need a primary key.

So, either I've found one of these very rare moments, or it's not that rare at all. My scenario seems quite simple and common, so there should be a more definite answer. Everything seems natural this way, I will never ever need to actually use a primary key. Therefore, I'd think it'd be simpler not to have one. Are there any really mysterious (and somewhat magical) ways of MySQL I'm overlooking? Or am I safe to leave out a useless auto-incrementing primary ID key (which could reach its limit way before any of the currently used ID's would, anyway) at least until I time I find a use for them (never)?

Comment: What a question!..? I saw "why is Post ID not primary" on the preview... the answer to which is simply because multiple users can like the same post.

Comment: That's why you have to read the _whole_ comment ;P Anyway, as you've probably seen, I've converted it into an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've said that Post ID and Member ID define the uniqueness of a column (and that Topic ID is secondary, included only for convenience).

So, why not have a primary key on `(Post ID, Member ID)`? If you already have `UNIQUE`ness constraints on them, then this is not a big leap.

```
CREATE TABLE `Likes` (
   `PostID`   INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   `TopicID`  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   `MemberID` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   `Date`     DATETIME     NOT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY (`PostID`, `MemberID`),
   FOREIGN KEY (`PostID`)   REFERENCES `Posts`   (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   FOREIGN KEY (`MemberID`) REFERENCES `Members` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) Engine=InnoDB;
```

<sup>(I don't know enough about `TopicID` to suggest key constraints for it, but you may wish to add some.)</sup>

Certainly adding an arbitrary auto-incrementing field is pointless, but that doesn't mean that you can't have a *meaningful* primary key.

As an aside, I'd consider removing the `TopicID` field; if you have your foreign keys set up properly then it should be trivial to do post<->topic lookup without it, and in this instance you're duplicating data and violating the relational model!

Comment: Well I'd like to know how to do that... I didn't know MySQL had tuples or how it would use them syntactically (C++/PHP guy myself). And there's no `UNIQUE`s, as each and every value could be used again. Only each particular row itself will be unique.

Comment: @Deji: The combined value of all three IDs is unique, isn't it? When you choose the primary key for your table, like any other key you do so by nominating one _or more_ columns to be part of it. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: only the Post ID and Member ID, actually. the Topic ID is a bit of a helper to do one query to get all relevant likes for the current page.

Comment: Heh, that was surprisingly easy and only a little different from my original method, thanks! (~3 minutes left to accept - stackoverflow underestimates its users)

Comment: @Deji "I didn't know MySQL had tuples": It does but that's not one of them. It's a sequence of column names, which is what a key is. "And there's no UNIQUEs, as each and every value could be used again.": You mischaracterize. UNIQUE/PK is for a *subrow* that can only appear once containing no smaller subrow that can.